# Pass query string to Modal Pop Up

Tags: asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

This is how my modal popup looks like

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtPatientID" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" runat="server" CssClass="csstextbox" Width="350px"></asp:TextBox>      

             <asp:Button ID="btnCheckPatientID" CssClass="cssbutton" runat="server" Text="Check" />
                                    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="btnCheckPatientID_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
                                        PopupControlID="panelCheckPatient" TargetControlID="btnCheckPatientID" BackgroundCssClass="modalbackground">
                                    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>            

            <div class="modalpopup" id="panelCheckPatient" style="display: none">
                                <iframe id="iframeCheckPatient" runat="server" width="485px" src="Check_Patient.aspx"
                                    height="485px" scrolling="auto"></iframe>

                            </div>
```

On Click of btnCheckPatientID I have to pass txtPatientID.Text pass as querystring to Modalpopup (In modalpopup load an iframe) how do i do that?

Comment: you can do that by changing src of iframe like `"Check_Patient.aspx?id=123"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using jQuery:

```
$('#btnCheckPatientID').live("click", function() {
    // your existing page
    var url = "Check_Patient.aspx";
    // append value of textbox as querystring
    var newUrl = url + "?id=" + $('#txtPatientID').val();
    // update the src attribute of your iframe with the newUrl
    $('#iframeCheckPatient').attr("src", newUrl);
});
```

Binding "click" event of the button using "live" so that it survives changes. Set the "src" attribute of your iframe to new url by appending the value of textbox as a querystring.

Comment: Consider some explanation of your answer to help those not immediately familiar.